# Numbering start from 1A and not A1

Tags: excel, vba

[This is the latest image of my spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u70bY.png) I need to label cells using 1A, 1B, 1C, 1D and so on. Basically, the number appears first before alphabet when the Macro do numbering. What I have here is totally inverted. The numbering starts from A1 and not 1A. Can you help me to correct my code please? Thank you. These are my code:

```
Public A, B As Integer

Sub AutoOpen()
A = 1
B = 1
End Sub

Sub LabelTest()
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
SR = .Row
SC = .Column
LR = SR + .Rows.Count - 1
LC = SC + .Columns.Count - 1
End With

For Rcount = SR To LR
For CCount = SC To LC
Cells(Rcount, CCount).Value = Replace(Cells(A, B).Address, "$", "")
A = A + 1
If A = 5 Then A = 1: B = B + 1
Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you just use `Right("A1",1)&Left("A1",1)` where `"A1"` could be replaced by a variable - e.g. the result of your `Replace(Cells(A, B).Address, "$", "")`.  Or you could simply use `A & Mid("ABCDE",B,1)` (providing B is not less than 1 and not more than 5.)

Comment: Can you add example image spreadsheet? on what your trying to do

Comment: @YowE3K I tried to use **Right("A1",1)&Left("A1",1)** but the result is not what I want as the output is only A1 in all cells that I selected.

Comment: @0m3r This is the example of my spreadsheet:  I tried to insert an image in my comment but it can't.            
           
     A1 A2 A3 A4   
    B1 B2 B3 B4 C1 C2  
   C3 C4 D1 D2 D3 D4 E1 E2

Comment: @YowE3K Your second code works! Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42942189/edit) to your question

Comment: @YowE3K The second code is almost perfect but the output is like this: 1A 2A 3A 4A 1B 2B 3B 4B, what I need is 1A 1B 1C 1D 2A 2B 2C 2D. Can you please help me again?

Comment: @0m3r I attached an image in my post.

Comment: Its okay guys. I figured out the answer myself. Thank you for all the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for this post:

```
Public A, B As Integer

Sub AutoOpen()
A = 1
B = 1
End Sub

Sub LabelTest()
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
SR = .Row
SC = .Column
LR = SR + .Rows.Count - 1
LC = SC + .Columns.Count - 1
End With

For Rcount = SR To LR
For CCount = SC To LC
Cells(Rcount, CCount).Value = B & Mid("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", A, 1)

A = A + 1
If A = 5 Then A = 1: B = B + 1
Next
Next
End Sub`
```